# JavaScriptCompressor, CssCompressor and multi threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, yui, yui-compressor

I'm using a static class to wrap the [Yahoo YUI compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com):

```
public static class Minifier
{
    private static readonly ICompressor javaScriptCompressor = 
                                                   new JavaScriptCompressor()
    {
        CompressionType = CompressionType.Standard,
        IgnoreEval = true,
        ObfuscateJavascript = true,
        PreserveAllSemicolons = true
    };

    private static readonly ICompressor cssCompressor = new CssCompressor()
    {
        CompressionType = CompressionType.Standard,
        RemoveComments = true
    };

    public static string GetCompressedCss(string data)
    {
        //aaaand... action
        return cssCompressor.Compress(data);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if the compressor classes are thread save?

Comment: Just create a new instance every time and be safe by construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JavaScriptCompressor` is not thread safe and should be recreated upon use (it stores state). `CssCompressor` does not store state.